# Can't figure out how to sort a doubly linked list?

Tags: c++, sorting

I am trying to figure out how to sort a doubly linked list in ascending order but can't wrap my head around it.  For my header, I have the follow with select_sort being the function that sorts it.

```
#ifndef INTLIST_H
#define INTLIST_H

struct IntNode{
    int data;
    IntNode *next;
    IntNode(int data) : data(data), next(0) {}
};

class IntList{
private:
    IntNode *head;
    IntNode *tail;
public:
    void select_sort();
```

Edit:

My horrible function

```
void IntList::select_sort(){
    for(IntNode *holder = head; holder != NULL; holder = holder -> next){
            IntNode *temp2 = holder;
            for(IntNode *temp = holder -> next; temp!=NULL;temp = temp->next){
                if(temp2 -> data > temp -> data){
                    temp2 = temp;
                }
            }
            int holder2 = tail -> data;
            tail -> data = temp2 -> data;
            temp2 -> data = holder2;
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: Added my horrible function

Comment: Since your data is just integers, you should use the [bucket sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort) algorithm.  Bucket sort is especially easy to implement for linked lists, and it also has computational complexity O(n), which some people will tell you is impossible, so it's great for winning arguments with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selection sort basically finds the smallest element in the remainder of the list and swaps it with the end of the sorted list, conceptually moving from left to right until you reach the end of the list.  After the first pass of the outer loop, the first element of the list has the lowest value.  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) has some excellent animations of selection sort in action.

You need a pointer to track the node with the lowest value starting at holder.

```
IntNode *min = holder;
```

Then if the current node, temp, is less than min, update min to point to temp.  After the inner for loop you just need to swap min and holder if they aren't the same so the smallest element in the remainder of the list is now at the end of the sorted list.

Comment: I edited my q with my revised function but it isn't working properly

Comment: You need to swap holder->data and temp2->data.  You are finding the smallest node in the sublist between holder and tail (inclusive) then swapping it with holder.